# Is MakeBoxes applied recursively, or just at top level?

Tags: front-end, formatting, boxes

I ask because I'm trying to make `Times[a, z^-1] //TraditionalForm` display as $a z^{-1}$ rather than $a/z$.  If I write

```
MakeBoxes[Power[z, n_Integer], TraditionalForm] :=
  ToBoxes[Superscript[z,n], TraditionalForm];
```

then `z^-1 //TraditionalForm` displays as $z^{-1}$, as expected, but `Times[a, z^-1] //TraditionalForm` gives me $a/z$.  If I add

```
MakeBoxes[head_[a__,Power[z, n_Integer]], TraditionalForm] :=
  ToBoxes[head[a, Superscript[z,n]], TraditionalForm];
```

then I get my desired result $a z^{-1}$, so it appears that `MakeBoxes` is applied at the top level only.  Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: With your first code piece, you can  use  `MapAll` , i.e., with `TraditionalForm//@ (a z^(-1))`  formating reaches  the `Power`s that lie deeper. For example: `TraditionalForm //@ ( (a z^(-1) + w^(y^(-2)))^(-3) + x^(-5))`

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not interpreting this correctly, at least not entirely.

`MakeBoxes` is always applied recursively, unless the formatting rule for an outer expression decideds hijack the process for an inner expression.  If this didn't happen, how could `{Red, Disk[]}` display as a list of a red swatch and the word `Disk[]`, but `Graphics[{Red,Disk[]}]` give you an actual red disk?

This is basically what you are running into here.  In fact, your comment above about `Times[a, Power[z,-1]]` reducing to `Divide[a,z]` is essentially completely reversed.  A symbolic fraction is a product of one or more `Power` expressions:

```
In[124]:= a/b //FullForm
Out[124]//FullForm= Times[a,Power[b,-1]]
In[125]:= a /( c b) //FullForm
Out[125]//FullForm= Times[a,Power[b,-1],Power[c,-1]]
```

For this reason, the formatting rule of `Times` explictly ignores the formatting rules of `Power` while it's formatting.  Your second rule works because it is circurmvents `Times` formatting, and in fact it would work just as well for your purposes (and be faster) if you wrote it like this:

```
MakeBoxes[Times[a___, Power[z, n_Integer]], TraditionalForm] := ToBoxes[a Superscript[z, n], TraditionalForm];
```

Note that you risk possibly reordering terms in the product this way, but if you always want the z^-1 at the end you're probably OK.  Of course, you also need the first rule for when z^-1 appears on its own, or inside a different function which doesn't hijack the recursion (which should be just about all functions).

About `MakeBoxes` more generally: `MakeBoxes` is a kernel function.  The order of evaluation is

1. The FE sends boxes to the kernel
2. All steps described in "The Main Loop", culminating in complete evaluation of the input and applying $PrePrint.
3. The kernel calls MakeBoxes on the result, and transmits the boxes to the FE to be inserted into the notebok.

The FE never "applies" any function, except in certain simple cases inside of Dynamic expressions and controls.  If it doubt, it will transmit things to the kernel make sure they are computed properly, and the make use of the result.

Comment: This is very enlightening.  I don't understand the phrase "...unless the formatting rule for an outer expression decideds hijack the process for an inner expression."  Is there a rule for deciding when to hijack the process, or are these irregular heuristics?

Comment: With very few execptions, the hijacking is obvious.  Things like Graphics(3D), Graph, Image, obviously are not necessarily formatting the individual expressions inside of them via the normal rules of those expressions on their own.  A less obvious example is SpanFromLeft on its own vs inside a Grid.  Due to the vagaries of mathematical notation and our own fullform, there are special rules for +,-, *, /, ^, and their combinations.  I'm sure there are a few others, though I can't think of any off of the top of my head.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev You wrote "`MakeBoxes` is always applied recursively, unless the formatting rule for an outer expression decides hijack the process for an inner expression." Do you mean that the Documentation statement [cited by Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151488/is-makeboxes-applied-recursively-or-just-at-top-level#comment404099_151491) is wrong? Obviously your statement directly contradicts the Documentation.

Comment: I suppose it depends on your interpretation of the meaning of "applied recursively."  The default formatting rules, for example for `f[args___]`, will call MakeBoxes and thus look up all definitions for each of the arg_i.  In that sense the problem in this case isn't that MakeBoxes isn't called recursively, it's that Times has very special formmating rules.  It is true tail definitions `MakeBoxes[...]:=...` will not call MakeBoxes again unless explictly present on the RHS.  So if you do `MakeBoxes[foo,StandardForm]:=2+bar`, you will get a pink box as output.

Comment: So `Times` has special processing rules, which hijack the normal recursive application of `MakeBoxes`.  @CarlWoll's answer therefore confuses me.  It clearly shows a reduction from `Times[a,Power[z,-1]]` to `Divide[a,z]`.  When I execute `Divide[a,z]//FullForm`, however, I get `Times[a,Power[z,-1]]` as @ItaiSeggev says I should.  What's going on?

Comment: We need to distinguish between evaluation rules and formatting rules.  `Divide[a,b]` for symbolic `a` and `b` always evaluates to `a*b^-1`.  Now, `MakeBoxes` is `HoldAllComplete` and does not allow evaluation to occur.  So what you are seeing in Carl's `TracePrint` is that the formatting rule for `Times` will in many cases rewrite an expression as `Divide[num,denom` and allow the formatting rules for `Divide` to fire.  (A fact I had forgotten.)  I may teak my answer to make this clearer...

Comment: Is there any documentation for all this special behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can see what is going on by using [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint):

```
TracePrint[
    MakeBoxes[a z^-1,TraditionalForm],
    _MakeBoxes,
    TraceInternal->True,
    TraceAction->(Print[FullForm[#]]&)
]
```

> HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Times[a,Power[z,-1]],TraditionalForm]]
>
> HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Times[a,Power[z,-1]],TraditionalForm]]
>
> HoldForm[MakeBoxes[Divide[a,z],TraditionalForm]]
>
> HoldForm[MakeBoxes[a,TraditionalForm]]
>
> HoldForm[MakeBoxes[z,TraditionalForm]]
>
> FractionBox["a", "z"]

From the above, we can see that your initial [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) for [`MakeBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MakeBoxes) never fires.

Comment: All right, so in the absence of the second `MakeBoxes` definition, `Times[a,Power[z,-1]]` reduces to `Divide[a,z]` before the first definition can fire.  Put the second definition in place, and it fires before the reduction happens.  Therefore `MakeBoxes` is applied recursively (in the front end, presumably).  Does this mean that every time a reduction happens (in the kernel) that `MakeBoxes` matches against it?

Comment: From the documentation: MakeBoxes is not automatically called on the results it generates. This means that explicit MakeBoxes calls must typically be inserted into definitions that are given.

Comment: @CarlWoll that isn't relevant here, as he is calling `ToBoxes` on the RHS

Comment: @ItaiSeggev I'm not sure what you're objecting to here, but my `TracePrint` clearly shows that `MakeBoxes[Power[z, -1], TraditionalForm]` is never called, hence the OP format value never gets triggered. I don't know what that has to do with the use of `ToBoxes` on the RHS side of his `MakeBoxes[Power[z, n_Integer], TraditionalForm]` rule that never gets called.

Comment: I was objecting to "From the documentation: MakeBoxes is not automatically called on the results it generates. This means that explicit MakeBoxes calls must typically be inserted into definitions that are give."  That has no bearing on on either his rules, or even really to his suggestion about when MakeBoxes is called.